# CMake finding 32bit GDI+ on 64 bit platform

Tags: windows, cmake

I want to build a program that requires GDI+ on both 32-bit and 64-bit windows.
I am using CMake 3.3.2, Windows 10 64-bit, Visual Studio 2015.
As a minimal case I have this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
find_library(GDIP gdiplus)
```

I run this in the build sub-directory as

```
cmake ..
```

or

```
cmake -A x64 ..
```

If I compare the CMakeCache.txt for both runs I see it definitely has picked 32 or 64 bit options (e.g. for `CMAKE_LINKER`) but it has found the 32-bit `gdiplus.lib` in both cases

```
//Path to a library.
GDIP:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x86/gdiplus.lib
```

It should find the 64 bit version `C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x64/gdiplus.lib` instead.

Is there a way to get this right?

Comment: Possibly, passing `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE=x64` to cmake should work. Cannot check that now.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that had no effect, sorry. Do you know if it's possible to print the list of paths that `find_library` will check?

Comment: Full search algorithm of `find_library` is described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_library.html). Now I see why my way with `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` variable shouldn't work for you: it works only for `**lib**/<arch>/<name>` cases. You may try to pass `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Lib/winv6.3/um/x86`. As the last resort you can set `GPID` variable manually to required lib.

Comment: Looking at CMake's bug tracker it seems to me like they haven't fully sorted out 64-bit toolchains yet. e.g. https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15622 Thanks for your help, I'll take it up with them.

Comment: Many thanks for this; I was pulling my hair out over this one...

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the CMake mailing list. I am indebted to Sergei Nikulov for his answer:
http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2015-October/061806.html

> One idea, how I've created workaround it for odbc lib:
>   Remove `find_library(GDIPLUS_LIBRARY NAMES libgdiplus gdiplus)`
>   and
>   `set(GDIPLUS_LIBRARY gdiplus)`
>   or another proper name.
>   Visual studio will pick it from proper path depending on target x86 or x86_64."

I don't think this is ideal but it does work. Thanks Sergei.

Comment: Works for MinGW-64 as well as Visual Studio. No idea how.